# PDO Arrays are not structured as expected

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm selecting rows from a database table through PDO and trying to fetch as an array so that I can use a foreach to build a list of links to each one. However, it's being indexed strangely.

The rows in the database are:

```
NAME        | DESCRIPTION          | EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP | EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
News Test   |Testing Page Library  |2018-07-13 00:00:00  |2018-07-14 00:00:00
Social Test |Testing Page Library2 |2018-07-13 00:00:00  |2018-07-14 00:00:00
```

However, the array currently looks like this:

```
Array ( [NAME] => News Test [0] => News Test [DESCRIPTION] => Testing page library [1] => Testing page library [EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP] => 2018-07-13 00:00:00[2] => 2018-07-13 00:00:00 [EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP] => 2018-07-14 00:00:00 [3] => 2018-07-14 00:00:00 )
Array ( [NAME] => Social Test [0] => Social Test [DESCRIPTION] => Testing page library2 [1] => Testing page library2 [EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP] => 2018-07-13 00:00:00 [2] => 2018-07-13 00:00:00 [EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP] => 2018-07-14 00:00:00 [3] => 2018-07-14 00:00:00 )
```

So it seems like it's doubling up each row, and indexing it strangely. I'm just trying to use PDO to fetch these 2 rows, each row as an array indexed by column because I want to echo links to each one on the page.

How should I change my fetch and/or foreach loop to fix this? I've never seen this happen in this way.

getPages.php

```
$getContent = "SELECT * 
                FROM testSchema.page
                ";

try{
    $contentFetch = $DB2Conn->prepare($getContent);
    $contentResult = $contentFetch->execute();
    $fetchResult = $contentFetch->fetchAll();
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY FAILED: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Pages.php

```
<?php foreach($fetchResult as $page): ?>
<h2><?php print_r($page) ?></h2>  //This is what prints the incorrect array above
<?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php in your case you shoud  `$fetchResult = $contentFetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Ha, perfect! Thanks so much. If you want to make an answer I'll go ahead and except it!

Comment: No that is just fine. It is not the answer :-) Good luck with your project.

Comment: As @Alex mentioned you should specify fetching method. But how it bothers you when you get both name and numeric indexes? You just use one of them and skip other indexing style. Only lost is on memory.

Comment: You can also specify the default fetch mode in your `new PDO()` call.

Comment: `print_r()` is just for debugging, the extra elements in the rows shouldn't affect how you process it in your application.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I changed it to echo after the fix!